# Should we have badges for high-voted comments?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, comments, badges

Bronze for 10, silver for 25, gold for 100?  I had a notion that there used to be such badges, but I can't be sure.

Comment: I *suppose* this could use migration to MSO, but let's see what others think.

Comment: Do we really need more badges? Really?

Comment: I think it has been stated that it is fine to ask such questions on a meta site that is not MSO.

Comment: Previously discussed and declined at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45580/more-badges-for-comments-bronze-and-gold-versions-of-pundit.

Comment: This is a discussion; does [meta-tag:status-declined] have any meaning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is already a [silver badge for 10 comments that have been up-voted 5 times](https://english.stackexchange.com/badges/24/pundit). It is a silver badge because it's not easy to get at least 5 up-votes on 10 different comments, and that can be classified as "longer term goal."
The equivalent bronze badge is [Commentator](https://english.stackexchange.com/badges/17/commentator).

There are no gold badges because comments are second class citizens; badges that would have the effect of increasing the number of comments (which is what I saw happening in some cases in some SE sites) would not have a good effect on an SE site, as questions and answers are the main focus. Between questions and answers, it's then the answers that have more importance.

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been asked twice at MSO, look at the following:

[More badges for comments / Bronze and gold versions of “Pundit”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45580/165097)

[Can we have a badge for up-voted comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99833/165097)

This request has already been rejected twice, but it's still a good idea. I reckon if we had more support for this proposal, it might come into being.